# PHP File Upload Form Use Filename as hidden variable

Tags: php

I have a simple file upload form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select PDF to upload:
    <input type="file" name="image" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"/>
</form>
```

I need to get the file names of multiple files selected and insert them as a hidden variable less the .jpg extention.  Example: 123.jpg I need to store as a hidden variable 123.  You'll notice this is complicated by needing to do this with multiple files.

To start I tried to use getFilename function but it does not work:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select PDF to upload:
    <input type="file" name="image" multiple/>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fileinfo->getFilename() ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"/>
</form>
```

How do I go about getting the filenames stored as a hidden variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit the request for PHP to grab the filename..

I would change

```
<input type='file' name='image' muliple/>
```

to

```
<input type='file' name='images[]' multiple />
```

And then in your `upload.php` file, you can grab the file names by doing this:

`$images = $_FILES['images'];`

Then if you wanted to get each name you could just use a foreach to loop through the multiple image names and grab them, or set them to anything you want.

```
foreach($images as $image){
    $names[] = $image['name'];
}
```

Then upload the file with the name you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the name for the hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $fileinfo->getFilename() ?>">
```